# How to convert javafx.scene.paint.Color to java.awt.Color ?

Tags: java, javafx, colors, awt, javafx-8

How to convert **javafx.scene.paint.Color** to **java.awt.Color** in java? 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [the constructor that accepts r,g,b and alpha parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-float-float-float-float-):

```
javafx.scene.paint.Color fx = ...;

java.awt.Color awtColor = new java.awt.Color((float) fx.getRed(),
                                             (float) fx.getGreen(),
                                             (float) fx.getBlue(),
                                             (float) fx.getOpacity());
```