# Is it possible to use Color Hex in JLabel like #02f7fc?

Tags: java, swing, colors, label

Is it possible to use `Color` hex in `JLabel` such as `#02f7fc`?
I want to use A-F colors. Using `label.setForeground(Color.(BLUE/RED/BLACK/…);` is so boring.

Comment: `new Color(r,g,b)` ..see the [`Color` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#constructor.summary) for more options.

Comment: Note: It's possible to use hex colors in HTML, and a label supports (basic) HTML, but it would be a hack to use HTML in a label purely for using the hex color.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should allow you to set the colour using hex with the use of the decode method.

```
label.setForeground(Color.decode("#FFFF00"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39078746/230513) due to @[assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias), the following method converts a [`javafx.scene.paint.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) to a [`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

```
private static Color awtColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color fxColor) {
    return new Color(
        (float) fxColor.getRed(),
        (float) fxColor.getGreen(),
        (float) fxColor.getBlue(),
        (float) fxColor.getOpacity());
}
```

With a suitable `import` statement, you can then leverage the JavaFX `Color` API. This example uses `Color.web()` to create "an RGB color specified with an HTML or CSS attribute string."

```
import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.web;
…
label.setForeground(awtColor(web("0xF0F8FF"))); // ALICEBLUE
label.setForegroundn(awtColor(web("AliceBlue"))); // #F0F8FF
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Andrew said, you can use a [new Color(int rgb)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HexColorTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(makeLabel(new Color(0xff0000)));
    p.add(makeLabel(new Color(Integer.parseInt("#00ff00".substring(1), 16))));
    p.add(new JLabel("<html><span style='color: #0000ff'>#0000ff"));
    return p;
  }
  private static JLabel makeLabel(Color c) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(String.format("#%06x", c.getRGB() & 0xffffff));
    label.setForeground(c);
    return label;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new HexColorTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it as background then you can do:

```
label.setBackground(Color.decode("#02f7fc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the color by doing:

```
label.setBackground(new Color(0x02f7fc))
```